# Is it possible to deploy a contract from browser-solidity for the Mainnet?

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, remix, metamask

I really have more than one doubt on what's the best way to deploy a smart contract.

First I thought was good enough paste the code directly inside **Mist/Ethereum Wallet** than I saw so many warnings (like `throw()`) that makes me move outside.

Is it correct deploying a contract for the **Mainnet** using [browser-solidity](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/) and **Metamask**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found much better using [browser-solidity](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity) inside Mist directly without Metamask.

Infact using the browser you can connect to the page your account and injected Web3 as usual.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12086)

Comment: @RichardHorrocks, I think OlivierRikken is saying that there shouldn't be any problems deploying a contract on the main net using browser-solidity and Metamask, which does in fact answer the question. (Perhaps you were replying to something that has since been deleted)

Comment: @lungj My question was made for asking to someone who already did in the real life, I know that probably it's possible but I would like (for my knowledge) to be 100% sure

Comment: @RichardHorrocks I was answering it indeed stating that to the best of my knowledge that it should be possible to use browser solidity and metamask to deploy a contract on the main net.

Comment: @NineCattoRules I don't know anyone who did it that way, but you could try with an extremely simple contract with no further functions in it and see if the address is created correcty? (this to minimize the amount of gas you will lose).

Comment: "I don't know anyone who did it that way" ...same here, I was just curious about it. (by the way I didn't downvote ;) )

Comment: @NineCattoRules but you can upvote ;-)